# MyBatis - Connect to multiple databases in the same service call

Tags: java, guice, mybatis

I have a requirement to connect to multiple databases to query and consolidate data before returning it to the users. Is there a way of doing it using MyBatis and cdi? I looked into using [DatabaseIdProvider](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#databaseIdProvider) and having [multiple environment configurations](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#environments) but looks like they will not work for this scenario. With multiple environment configurations I can create different sql session factories, but how will cdi for mappers work in that case? I would like to use cdi as much as possible. Will MyBatis Guice help with this? I have looked at a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917115/equivalent-of-mybatis-xml-multiple-environments-in-mybatis-guice) question but I am unable to determine if Guice will help in this case where I need to query multiple databases in the same service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment configuration define datasource and transaction manager.
Then connecting to multiple databases requires at least as much *SqlSessionFactory*:

```
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(classpathConfigFilename);
new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, environment, properties);
```

Call one for each *environment*

If the purpose is to consolidate data, I guess both data models are slightly different (then so are queries, mappers, typeHandler ...), then SqlSessionFactory would better be created from different mybatis-config files and use their default environment:

```
new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, properties);
```

How so it does not solve the issue?
A more accurate answer might be brought if you edit the question to provide more information about context, examples, what you have tried.

Guice: may of course be used, but is not required for this achievement.

EDIT:

Use [Mybatis-CDI](http://www.mybatis.org/cdi/injection.html)

Here is how to produce SqlSession factories (they must be *@Named*):

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Named;

public class SqlSessionFactoryWrapper {

    private static final String  BI_CONFIG  = "mybatis-config.xml";

    private SqlSessionFactory getFactory(final String config, final String env) throws IOException {
        final Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(config);
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(Resources.getResourceAsReader("some.properties"));

        return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader, env, properties);
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("A")
    public SqlSessionFactory getFactoryA() throws IOException {
        return this.getBiFactory(CONFIG, "A");
    }

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named("B")
    public SqlSessionFactory getFactoryB() throws IOException {
        return this.getFactory(CONFIG, "B");
    }
}
```

And how to inject:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;


    @Inject
    @Named("A")
    protected SqlSession          sessionA;

    @Inject
    @Named("B")
    protected SqlSession          sessionB;
```

Or *inject* directly *mapper* for from *SqlSession* of environment *B*:

```
import org.mybatis.cdi.Mapper;

    @Inject
    @Named("B")
    @Mapper
    protected MyMapper mapper;
```

This is working in my app running in jBoss, but there is nothing jBoss-specific here.

Read the [documentation for transaction management](http://www.mybatis.org/cdi/transactions.html), this is pretty clear.
I recommend using

```
@Transactional(executorType = ExecutorType.REUSE)
```

specialy for bulk operations to prepare statements only once.

EDIT2:

mybatis.cdi annotations in snippets are valid for version 1.0.0.beta3 I was using then. In further betas they have slightly evolved, then few adaptation is required to work with final release  (out for just a month).

Answer (score 1):

You will need 2 SqlSessionFactories defined. Separate environments may suit your needs, but it's also possible to use completely separate configurations and object / class hierarchies. Regardless, you can pass each one as needed in the configuration for your mappers or the mapper scanner.

See the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html) for the various ways to configure your mappers. Note that all of them allow you to specify the SqlSessionFactory, if needed. If each configuration is using the same mappers, you might not be able to use the scanner approach since that I think that will use the same names for mappers from different SqlSessionFactories. In that case you will have to manually configure your mappers using different names for different configs.

Then in your service you can do something like:

```
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("fooMapperDB1")
  private FooMapper fooMapper1;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("fooMapperDB2")
  private FooMapper fooMapper2;

  public List<Foo> doService(String id) {
    List<Foo> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    toReturn.add(fooMapper1.getFoo());
    toReturn.add(fooMapper2.getFoo());
    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

Note that you need to be careful here with transactions. You probably want the service to be transactional and then use distributed XA datasources for both DB connections.